# MarkLogic on Centos 7.2 on raspberry PI 2 B

Tags: marklogic, marklogic-8

Did anyone try to install MarkLogic on CENTos 7.2 on raspberry pi 2 B?

I am running into problem when trying this:

> [root@rpi2 marklogic]# rpm -i MarkLogic-8.0-4.2.x86_64.rpm error:
>   Failed dependencies:  lsb is needed by MarkLogic-8.0-4.2.x86_64
>     libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.11)(64bit) is needed by MarkLogic-8.0-4.2.x86_64
>     libgcc_s.so.1()(64bit) is needed by MarkLogic-8.0-4.2.x86_64
>     libstdc++.so.6()(64bit) is needed by MarkLogic-8.0-4.2.x86_64

No matter what I tried I could not get listed libs to install all and without errors. I suspect this is still not supported but wanted to double check. The pi is 32 bit so 64 bit install is probably the issue.

Thanks,

Zoran

Comment: Even if there were a 64-bit Pi, this is not a good idea. MarkLogic is designed for relatively big machines. A "small machine" according to their provisioning recommendations is orders of magnitude more powerful than a Pi.

Comment: The installation guide lists [Memory, Disk Space, and Swap Space Requirements](http://docs.marklogic.com/guide/installation/intro#id_11335), as well as [Supported Platforms](http://docs.marklogic.com/guide/installation/intro#id_63469). One of the requirements is a 64-bit system.

Comment: While it's still probably a bad idea, the Pi 3 is 64 bit, and may support your needs.

Comment: I agree it would not be good performance but as a sand box or learn environment you could have 4 node cluster for $200 ... The problem is that on centos72 cut for rpi3 and running in pi3 the lib errors show up when rpm -I is run as above ... I could not get around them

Comment: ... to Dave's point - yes - centos72 64 bit for pi3 is  pending but I thought that there was another library that might help with that - if not then 64bit centos  for  pi3 will be the next step.

Answer (score 1):

I installed MarkLogic 8.0-4.2 in Centos 6 and it works fine. I don't see MarkLogic rpm available for Centos 7 yet. Try using Centos 6.

Comment: Did you use centos 6 for raspberry pi? I only found images for centos 7 for raspberry pi.

Comment: I believe Centos only started releasing images for arm chips recently and so far it is only 32 bit; raspberry pi is arm chip.